# Laravel update Session manually

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, session-cookies, laravel-5.4

I am using `Laravel` 5.4 and I am using  builtin `Auth` so Logging in - out comping behind the scene and it's storing the session automatically.
How can I add more information to my session  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to build a custom Login function, you could go to 
`AuthenticatesUsers` file which handle this task and inside method called

```
 authenticated(Request $request, $user)
```

You can add whatever you want.

This file can be found in

`vendor`->`Laravel`->`framework`->`src`->`Illuminate`->`Foundation`->`Auth`

Answer (score 1):

Nour answer works but it's better if dont write code directly in vendor files, it can be overwritten by any `composer update`.

Instead you can add a function `authenticated(Request $request, $user)` directly in your `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController` and write your custom code that fires on every successful authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you store in your user table will be stored in session data after log in you just need to access it like this
Auth::user()->column_name

Comment: I don't want data from my table I want different data